# How to create an htaccess rewrite rule with part of parameter as identifier

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need some help with a rewrite rule I am struggling with.

I have the existing rule below, which works well and redirects as follows:

```
www.site.com/page.php?type=1&category=2&cond=3
redirected to
www.site.com/1/2/3/

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /page.php?type=$1&category=$2&cond=$3 [L]
```

Now I need to create one new rule that will not interfere with the rule above.

So this url:

```
www.site.com/page.php?type=1&category=2&page=page-1
should redirect to:
www.site.com/1/2/page-1/
```

Obviously, the browser should make somehow the difference between `www.site.com/1/2/3/` and `www.site.com/1/2/page-1/`.

This difference can be the part of the third parameter which will be always constant: `page-` .

I know I need to somehow modify this part of the new rule `([^/]*)` but nothing I have tried so far does to job.

Any suggestions how should I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do your rules this way.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/page-([^/]*)/?$ /page.php?type=$1&category=$2&page=page-$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /page.php?type=$1&category=$2&cond=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Have these 2 rules in this order:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(page-[^/]+)/?$ /page.php?type=$1&category=$2&cond=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /page.php?type=$1&category=$2&cond=$3 [L,QSA]
```